# How to ensure that service has been stopped or started using PowerShell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure-devops

I am running a task in `VSTS/Azure DevOps` pipeline to stop & uninstall a list of window services. What I am doing here is running below code & using sleep method to ensure that the above method has been completed.

```
Function DeleteService([string] $ServiceName) 
{
    TRY{

        $Service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$ServiceName'"  

        if ($Service -ne $null) 
        {
            Write-Output "Stopping window service - '$ServiceName'"         
            $Service.StopService()     
            # Adding a sleep for ten seconds to let the process stop the service completely
            Start-Sleep -m 10000 
            Write-Output "Stopping Window service - '$ServiceName' completed"   


            Write-Output "Uninstalling window service - '$ServiceName'"         
            $Service.Delete()   
            # Adding a sleep for ten seconds to let the process stop the service completely
            Start-Sleep -m 10000
            Write-Output "Uninstalling window service - '$ServiceName' completed"   

        } 
        else 
        {
            Write-Output "Window service - '$ServiceName' does not exist. Uninstallation Complete"
        }
    }
    CATCH
    {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message    
        Write-Error " ********************** Error in uninstalling window service : $ServiceName with exception $ErrorMessage ********************** "
    }
}
```

Isn't there a better approach in PowerShell that will acknowledge me that service has been stopped, now I can proceed. So that I don't have to put such patches in code.

Because, As I have studied from [Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service?view=powershell-6#description), that these commands sends the message to `Windows Service Controller`. They don't complete the task. So I am doubtful that how to write such code that will run synchronously with proper ontime execution.

Comment: Get-Service, Stop-Service & Remove-Service ([documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management)) [edit - PSv6 only for Remove-Service so might not help]

Comment: Do these methods complete their job before moving to the next line?

Comment: They're commands not methods, and yes they are synchronous. Note edit to my post about PSv6 - not sure what version your pipeline supports/uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PS v6 you can just use `Remove-Service` as this will stop and remove the service:

```
if (Get-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    Remove-Service $ServiceName -Verbose
} 
else {
    Write-Output "Window service - '$ServiceName' does not exist. Uninstallation Complete"
}
```

If you're on a lower version I'd use `Stop-Service` & `Get-CimInstance` (instead of Get-WmiObject):

```
if (Get-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    Stop-Service $ServiceName -Verbose
    Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$ServiceName'" | Remove-CimInstance
} 
else {
    Write-Output "Window service - '$ServiceName' does not exist. Uninstallation Complete"
}
```

Comment: Once this line is executed - "Remove-Service $ServiceName -Verbose". Can I be sure in next line that service has been removed from the system?

Comment: Yes if the command completes the service will be removed, you'll get a terminating error if it fails to remove the service.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Get-WmiObject` you can use `Get-Service` and check the status of the service:

```
$service = Get-Service -Name 'VSS'
Write-Host $service.Status
# Stopped/Running
```

So if you want to ensure the service is stopped and then continue to the deletion, you can wrap the status checking with while loop.

```
while ($service.Status -ne 'Running')
{
  ....
}
```